# Advanced File I/O Exercise for C++ not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++ final tomorrow and my prof said to make sure we could properly do this exercise:

1. Open a file called .txt as ios::out | ios::binary
2. Write an int containing the value 1 to the file.
3. Close the file
4. Open the file for ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary
5. Read the int
6. Seek to the first byte of the file
7. Add 1 to the int
8. Write the int back to the file.
9. Close the file.

here's the code I have for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("118394.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int x = 1;
    int y;

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(x), sizeof(x));

    file.close();

    file.open("118394.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(y), sizeof(y));

    file.seekp(0L, ios::beg);

    x++;

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(x), sizeof(x));

    file.close();


}
```

It will compile and run, but when it does I get a "bad access error".

[image: Here's a screenshot.]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Xcode.

Comment: You casting the variable as a pointer.  You need to take the address of the variable as in: `(char *) &x`.

Comment: Thanks so much! The program runs properly now. However, when it creates the file the file has nothing on it. Does the rest of my code look correspond with my professor's instructions correctly?

Comment: The `read` method requires an address also.  My understanding of the assignment is that you want to increment the `y` variable and write the `y` variable to the file.

Comment: The file will possibly look blank in a text editor, even if you're doing it right.  Binary data is not often legible characters.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it changed the question after someone had already answered it. If you still have a question that is a good fit for the site, you can ask it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `write` method is a location.

You need to pass it the location, or *address* of the variable.  The address of a variable can be obtained by using the `&` symbol e.g. `&x`.

So your write instruction would look like (using C style casting):

```
file.write((char *) &x, sizeof(x));
```

Similarly, the `read` method needs a location to place data in.  So your `read` operation would look like:

```
file.read((char *) &y, sizeof(y));
```

Also, you should increment the variable that you read in, i.e. `y`, and write that variable back to the file.

Comment: so I edited the code in the question and the file still comes out as blank. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x)` instead of `reinterpret_cast<char*> (x)`
and `reinterpret_cast<char*> (&y)` instead of `reinterpret_cast<char*> (y)`

`x` to `&x`
`y` to `&y`

if you open the file as a text file it may show strange characters as it is a binary file. Binary files usually look strange. It may look empty in yours case as the file is very small.

You can,though, add this line after the `file.read`

`cout << y;`

to check if you can read correctly from the file. (i.e. the file contains correct data).